# how to use the displayed text from combobox when it's filled by a query

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

My `ComboBox` is filled by using a query. I have a `SiloId` and a `SiloName`, So the `ID` is `combobox.ValueMember` and the name is `combobox.DisplayMember`.

Normally I need the `ID` when it's selected . (`combobox.SelectedValue`)
But now I need the text like it's displayed in the `ComboBox`.

How should I do that ?

Comment: Did you try comobbox.SelectedText ??

Comment: @Kram `SelectedText` is the text that is selected in the editable part of a `ComboBox`. I don't think that whats OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, Use `combobox.Text;`.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching to hard I guess. I tried everything from .SelectedText etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
combobox.Text;
```

or

```
combobox.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: `combobox.SelectedItem` is not necessarily the text displayed in the `combobox`.